# How to ignore Activity life cycle in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I just want to ignore the Activity life cycle.

I mean that I want to make the Activity is always on top of the window.

The Activity is not be destroyed even if the other Activity or App is executed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. It violates the Android Framework.

If you just want to do something all the time, in the background, you should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your words are really contradictory.

1. You want to ignore Activity life-cycle, which means you wanna run wild out-of-the-box
2. `The Activity is not be destroyed even if the other Activity or App is executed.` <--- yes, of course, from Activity A you start Activity B, Activity A is still alive according to the Activity life-cycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without changing the Android Code.